# How to pass data from main activity to a view class

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Im trying to pass two different arrays to the BarActivity class, but its a View class and wont let me use Intent to pass the information like i thought i could. Is there a way that I can pass these arrays to the bar activity so that I can actually start making the bar chart.

this is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
ListView listView;
ListAdapter listAdapter;
Button btnCompute;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText=findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btnCompute=findViewById(R.id.btnCompute);

    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {

                try
                {

                    if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    {
                        listAdapter=null;
                        listView.setAdapter(null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String[] arr =editText.getText().toString().split(",");
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BarActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("Grades", arr);
                        startActivity(i);
                        listAdapter=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,arr);
                        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    btnCompute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(listAdapter!=null)
            {
              
                Integer [] list=listAdapter.getList();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BarActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Values", list);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

And this is the BarActivity

```
 public class BarActivity extends View  {
//hash map
Map<String, Float> data = new HashMap<>();
private float barWidth = 60f;
private float barSpace = 20f;
private Paint mPaint;

// Intent i = getIntent();
// String[] myGrades = i.getStringArrayExtra("Grade");
// Intent intent = Intent.getIntentOld();
//  String[] myValues = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Values");
public BarActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) throws URISyntaxException {
    super(context, attrs);

    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // mRandom = new Random();

    data.put("A", 0.20f);
    data.put("A-", 0.12f);
    data.put("F", 0.1f);


}
@Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           
        
      }
```

The commented out part `// Intent i = getIntent()` isn't working at all; it's telling my to use `getIntentOld()` instead, which also doesn't work.

Comment: Sending part looks fine but you have not posted your receiving part

Comment: you are trying to open BarActivity like activity, but its view. Make it as an activity and inside it use a custom view class.